# Global selection of Company before interacting with any other forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm working on the design of a database for a client and they would like to work with one of their companies (customers) at a time throughout the entire session.

Ideally I would like to set up the forms so that they select the company to work with first and then can navigate to various other forms to manage the different aspects of that company (locations, departments, employees, etc.). There will obviously be many companies in the database, so I would need to ensure that they only see records for the selected company and adding new values ties them to the selected company.

I've been doing some searching around for how best to accomplish this but I've had no real luck.

Any guidance you can give would be awesome.

PS. I've got the structure of the database tables setup to ensure that any entity that is company-specific has a foreign key that identifies the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user enters the program, the first form they should see should be the company chooser form. Then the user can continue on to the other forms, which would all be filtered based on the user's initial selection.

You can either have the form write to a module-level variable, and all the forms would be filtered by the value of a function which would return the company ID to filter by.

It may be easier for you to simply hide the form, and filter all the successive forms by the value in the combo box of the hidden form.

You might also want to consider creating a query for each table, which contains only the filtered values per company (either with a function, or by the value of the hidden form) and basing all your forms/reports on those queries. That way you won't accidentally forget to include the filter in a form/report.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I think hiding the form will work best for me for now.  

The query idea is great - I didn't think of that but it definitely make sense to create the queries with the filter built in.  

Creating records with the selected Company ID should just be as easy as filtering based on the item selected in the combo box?

Comment: I'm having some issues using the combo box on the hidden form to save records back into the table when creating new ones. They need to be associated to the company selected at first.

If it's any help I've been using this to reference the company combo box in queries to filter:
'[Forms]![frmHome]![SelectedComp]'

Comment: I think the simplest idea is to set the [default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837160.aspx) of a hidden control bound to the company ID field, to your expression -- `=[Forms]![frmHome]![SelectedComp]`. If that doesn't work, then I suggest asking it as a new question, with more detail.

Comment: If this has answered the qeustion, please accept it, at least until another better/more comprehensive answer comes along. If this answer is useful, then please upvote.